# Plot two different dataframes with different dates- x axis is not ordered

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have two different dataframes. First one is High/Lows of a selected ticker from a selected time interval. Second dataframe includes special 'signals' occured at the same time interval.

df:

```
          Time      High       Low
0   29/03/22 16:00  47871.02  47105.50
1   29/03/22 20:00  47726.00  46950.85
2   30/03/22 00:00  47457.16  46445.42
3   30/03/22 04:00  47580.00  47140.46
4   30/03/22 08:00  47500.00  47064.81
5   30/03/22 12:00  47344.50  46869.00
6   30/03/22 16:00  47700.22  46831.81
7   30/03/22 20:00  47292.68  46850.00
8   31/03/22 00:00  47425.21  46973.91
9   31/03/22 04:00  47170.71  46898.12
10  31/03/22 08:00  47386.70  47000.00
11  31/03/22 12:00  47600.00  46230.00
12  31/03/22 16:00  46492.65  45500.00
13  31/03/22 20:00  45849.99  45200.00
14  01/04/22 00:00  45644.86  44200.00
15  01/04/22 04:00  45110.81  44547.11
16  01/04/22 08:00  45170.62  45008.24
```

dfs:

```
  Time Frame       Signal    Price            Time
0         4H  SELL[37/75]  47440.0  29/03/22 16:00
1         4H   BUY[43/75]  47701.0  29/03/22 20:00
2         4H   BUY[24/75]  47435.0  30/03/22 04:00
3         4H  SELL[38/75]  47384.0  30/03/22 08:00
4         4H  SELL[38/75]  47074.0  30/03/22 20:00
5         4H   BUY[44/75]  47161.0  31/03/22 08:00
6         4H  SELL[31/75]  47152.0  31/03/22 12:00
7         4H  SELL[51/75]  46454.0  31/03/22 16:00
```

So whenever i try to plot these two dataframes within the same plot:

[image]
It works fine. This is eaxactly what i want. Signal times matches with H/L times, so they blend to each other and even replacing duplicates on x axis. Because these are only Buy/Sell signals and they only occur at the close of each 4H candle etc.

But, whenever i change 'dfs' to this:

```
  Time Frame             Signal    Price            Time

0         4H  RESISTANCE[35/75]  47150.0  30/03/22 18:58
1         4H        SELL[38/75]  47074.0  30/03/22 20:00
2         4H     SUPPORT[39/75]  47113.0  31/03/22 05:27
3         4H         BUY[44/75]  47161.0  31/03/22 08:00
4         4H  RESISTANCE[31/75]  47157.0  31/03/22 08:22
5         4H        SELL[31/75]  47152.0  31/03/22 12:00
6         4H  RESISTANCE[26/75]  47132.0  31/03/22 13:18
7         4H        SELL[51/75]  46454.0  31/03/22 16:00
```

the result is this:
[image]

the x axis is not in order.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17.6, 9.6))
ax.plot(df['Time'], df['High'], marker='v', mec='blue',mfc='blue', ms=5, color = 'blue')
ax.plot(df['Time'], df['Low'], marker='v', mec='red',mfc='red', ms=5, color = 'red')
ax.tick_params(axis='x')
ax.scatter(dfs['Time'], dfs['Price'], color='black')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Tried to concat and merge two dataframes.
Also tried to plot secondary x axis.
no luck.
plotting with pandas plot doesnt solve the issue either.

I need a simple trick to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the combination of two facts:

- the `Time` column of the modified "dfs" contains dates that are not present in "df", contrary to the original "dfs";
- you are using **string** values for your `Time` columns, instead of **datetime** objects.

Before plotting, add these two lines of code:

```py
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"], format="%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
dfs["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(dfs["Time"], format="%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
```

And then, with "df" and modified "dfs", the plot is correct:
[image]